# How not to let the text over the button?

Tags: html, css, button, input

I found this example on the Internet. Can it fix in order to the text isn't over the button? Limit not by symbols, but visually.

**Now** it looks like this:

[image]

I would like **to do** this

[image]

Is that possible? I would like to use this template, but I have little experience to fix it. The template initially with such a bug. I didn't change anything. [Original](https://codepen.io/visualcookie/pen/kkwxPm).

Thanks in advance for any help!

```css
:root {
  background: #f5f6fa;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  font: 1rem "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}

html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}
a:hover {
  color: #7f8ff4;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn--primary {
  background: #7f8ff4;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 12px 36px;
}
.btn--primary:hover {
  background: #6c7ff2;
}
.btn--primary:active {
  background: #7f8ff4;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.btn--inside {
  margin-left: -96px;
}

.form__field {
  width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #a3a3a3;
  font: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 22px 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="container__item">
  <form class="form">
   <input type="email" class="form__field" placeholder="Your E-Mail Address" />
   <button type="button" class="btn btn--primary btn--inside uppercase">Send</button>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would a maxlength=”” parameter in the input type="email" field be good enough? You'd still have some calculation to do, but you could make sure things didn't spill over that way. I also don't see overlap as a problem in Firefox. You just can't see the right side of your (long) email address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try "padding-right" for the input

```css
:root {
  background: #f5f6fa;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  font: 1rem "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}

html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}
a:hover {
  color: #7f8ff4;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn--primary {
  background: #7f8ff4;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 12px 36px;
}
.btn--primary:hover {
  background: #6c7ff2;
}
.btn--primary:active {
  background: #7f8ff4;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.btn--inside {
  margin-left: -96px;
}

.form__field {
  width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #a3a3a3;
  font: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 22px 18px;
  padding-right:100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="container__item">
  <form class="form">
   <input type="email" class="form__field" placeholder="Your E-Mail Address" />
   <button type="button" class="btn btn--primary btn--inside uppercase">Send</button>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```